# SASS variables to CSS variables (gulp-sass)

Tags: css, node.js, variables, sass, gulp

I want to change with javascript some SASS/CSS variables to change the color of multiple elements.

How I can send SASS variables to CSS as variables?
I tryed it like in the  [documentation of Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars), but it gives me an error, on compiling the CSS.

**Here the Error:**

> ```
> Error in plugin "sass" Message:
> dev\sass\_settings.sass Error: Invalid CSS after "$primary-color: #ff2aad;": 
> expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "root: {"
>     on line 5 of dev/sass/_settings.sass
>     from line 1 of dev/sass/style.sass
>     $primary-color: #ff2aad;
> ```

**Here my SASS code:**

```
$primary-color: #ff2aad

:root
  --primary-color: #{$primary-color}
```

Im using an NodeJS enviroment with an gulpfile.js.
My gulp-sass version is 4.1.0

It passes if I remove this part:

```
:root
      --primary-color: #{$primary-color}
```

Maybe it exist an better way to manipulate SASS variables with javascript. If someone have an idea or documentation this would really help me

---

**Update / Solution:**

I found out by using an [CSS to SASS Converter](https://css2sass.herokuapp.com/) that I have to add an `\` before the `:root` Element

The Solution looks like this in SASS:

```
$primary_color: #ff2aad

\:root
  --primary_color: #{$primary_color}

h1 
  color: var(primary_color: #ff2aad);
```

I didn't found any documentation about this but it seams to work perfectly fine without error or issues.

Thanks on all that tryed to help. You Rock

Comment: Are you using `gulp-dart-sass` instead of `gulp-sass`?  That could fix it.

Comment: I found the solution with an CSS to SASS Converter. Before `:root` I have to put an \. 
`\:root`
  `--primary_color: #{$primary_color}`

I dont found any doc about this but no error or issues. All seems to work fine. 

But thanks for the help. Maybe in gulp-dart-sass it will be work without \ but I guess i dont need to download another npm module ^^

Comment: `gulp-dart-sass` supports `@use` for example which `gulp-sass` does not.

Comment: #{$primary-color}  awesome! Thanks for posting the find.